# Should I consider robots.txt when url is redirected to other domain?

Tags: http, redirect, web-crawler, robots.txt

I want to crawl some site on medium.com, custom domain.
(eg, https://uber-developers.news/)

These sites always redirect to "medium.com" and that returns back to the site. But a problem is here, the redirected url of medium.com is disallowed by its robots.txt.

Here is the way redirected.

1. https://uber-developers.news/
2. https://medium.com/m/global-identity?redirectUrl=https://uber-developers.news/
3. https://uber-developers.news/?gi=e0f8caa9844c

The problem is above the second url "https://medium.com/m/global-identity?redirectUrl=https://uber-developers.news/", disallowed by robots.txt

https://medium.com/robots.txt

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /m/
Disallow: /me/
Disallow: /@me$
Disallow: /@me/
Disallow: /*/*/edit
Allow: /_/
Allow: /_/api/users/*/meta
Allow: /_/api/users/*/profile/stream
Allow: /_/api/posts/*/responses
Allow: /_/api/posts/*/responsesStream
Allow: /_/api/posts/*/related
Sitemap: https://medium.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

Should I consider robots.txt of second url?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

`robot.txt` files are only indicating crawlers what they should do, but they, bye no means, can forbid crawlers from doing differently. What Medium does will stop polite and respectful crawlers only.

You need to follow the redirections (if you are using CURL for example, there is an option for this) and you will reach the page you want. But if you do this on a massive scale, Medium might not be happy about this.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. It is very useful to decide crawl medium.com or not. Maybe we won't crawl medium.com.